# How can I upload a zip multipart form file, extract it and upload it to S3 on the fly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I've got a nodeJS server which is receiving a zip file via a multipart form from a frontend and uploading it to S3.

This is achieved through a buffer like so:

`const buffer = fs.readFileSync(path)` and then uses the AWS SDK to upload to S3.

However is it possible to modify the stream to unzip the file and upload the files and directories to S3 on the fly?

I'd rather not download the files to server, extract them and then upload it for scaling reasons. It seems like Lambdas are the only other option but that's a post upload action.

Can I unzip the file as I receive from the frontend and upload the unzipped contents to S3?

Comment: There is nothing readily available in AWS SDK for this.

Comment: Perhaps you could use the unzip-stream package or similar which would give you event handlers for each entry in the ZIP file and you could use those to upload individual files to S3.